# Delimited sized columns in notepad++

Tags: text-editors, text-editing

I'm currently building string messages to send to an IBM server.

Basically we have the definition of the fields, but when I build the message using notepad or Notepad++ sometimes I make mistakes because these are very long fields.

Example:

```
Message definition:
User:String 40 chars
Workstation:String 20 chars
Path:100 chars
```

Is there a way in Notepad++ to define column sizes to fill later?

Something like this:

`[              ][           ][             ]`

`[User1         ][Workstation][Path         ]`

Output:

`User1         WorkstationPath`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a work around:
you can prepare one line with the template you have in mind, copy/paste it several times, fill it with the text you want and then (saving a backup) replace the strings that limit the spaces with blanks.

Another way would be to use Excel (maybe [limiting](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/952-excel-cell-character-limit.html) the content's length for every column) and export it to a formatted text file (see [this SuperUser page](https://superuser.com/questions/100433/export-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-fixed-width-text-file)).